# Stream webapp as video feed

Tags: java, javascript, html

I have a webapp that runs on a pi thats just a animation. Now the pi struggles when there is loads of animation happening. What I would like to do is render the app on the server and stream is as a video feed to the pi thus taking all the javascript processing away from the pi.

How would I go about doing that? The app has a java backend serving up the html.

Comment: Do you have freedom of browser on the pi? It looks like there is an html5 browser in the works: http://www.raspberrypi.org/web-browser-beta/ - or could it be played in a video application on the pi?

Comment: Im currently running a xserver on the pi and using chromium as the browser. But need to take the browser rendering away from the client and onto the server and just feed it as video to the client

Comment: Going to give the raspberrypi.org/web-browser-beta a go and see if the ARMv6-optimized 2d rendering makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

So in light of the comments, you're saying you want to entirely take the rendering of the screen content away from the Pi, and instead stream it from a server.

For that, I would look at installing a media-centre OS on the Pi, like Kodi (was XBMC)/Raspmc or OpenELEC, and at the server using a video streaming application (if the content is static).

If, instead, you really do want a web page, and only part of it is an animation, then try using the [raspberrypi.org/web-browser-beta](http://www.raspberrypi.org/web-browser-beta/), with appropriate streaming again from the server.

In both cases, check the available codecs from the stream server and the client; h264 is likely to be your best bet, particularly as the browser should be able to accelerate h264 decoding using the video core on the Pi.

Aside: Consider asking a question directly regarding your animation, in case it is possible to do it on the Pi itself; it can be surprising what optimisations are out there.